# JQuery form sticks with the ajax indicator on and won't submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using JQuery 1.3 to validate and submit a form to a PHP page which JSON encodes a server response to display on the original form page.

I've tried submitting the form without the JQuery part and everything seems to work fine but when I add JQuery it doesn't submit and constantly displays the ajax indicator.

Here's my code:

$(document).ready(function(){

var options = { 
        target: '#messagebox',
        url:  'updateregistration.php',
  type:'POST',
  beforeSubmit: validatePassword,
  success: processJson,
        dataType:  'json'
     }; 
 $("form:not(.filter) :input:visible:enabled:first").focus(); 
 $("#webmailForm").validate({

errorLabelContainer: "#messagebox",
 rules: {
     forename: "required",
  surname: "required",
  currentpassword: "required",
  directemail: {
       required: true,
       email: true
     },
   directtelephone: "required"
   },
   messages: {
    forename: { required: "Please enter your forename
" },
 directemail: { required: "Please enter your direct e-mail address
", email: "Your e-mail address does not appear to be valid
(Example: name@domain.com)
" },
 surname: { required: "Please enter your surname
" },
 directtelephone: { required: "Please enter your direct telephone number
" },
 currentpassword: { required: "Please enter your current password
" }

}

});

$('#webmailForm').submit(function() {

$('#ajaxindicator').show();

```
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    return false; 
});
```

});

function processJson(data) { 
 $("#webmailForm").fadeOut("fast");
 $("#messagebox").fadeIn("fast");
 $("#messagebox").css({'background-image' : 'url(../images/messageboxbackgroundgreen.png)','border-color':'#009900','border-width':'1px','border-style':'solid'});
 var forename=data.forename;
 var surname=data.surname;
 var directemail=data.directemail;
 var directphone=data.directphone;
 var dateofbirth=data.dateofbirth;
 var companyname=data.companyname;
 var fulladdress=data.fulladdress;
 var telephone=data.telephone;
 var fax=data.fax;
 var email=data.email;
 var website=data.website;
 var fsanumber=data.fsanumber;
 var membertype=data.membertype;
 var network=data.network;

```
$("#messagebox").html('<h3>Registration Update successful!</h3>' + '<p><strong>Member Type:</strong> ' + membertype + '<br>' + '<strong>Forename:</strong> ' + forename + '<br><strong>Surname:</strong> ' + surname + '<br><strong>Direct E-mail:</strong> ' + directemail + '<br><strong>Direct Phone:</strong> ' + directphone + '<br><strong>Date of Birth:</strong> ' + dateofbirth + '<br><strong>Company:</strong> ' + companyname + '<br><strong>Address:</strong> ' + fulladdress + '<br><strong>Telephone:</strong> ' + telephone + '<br><strong>Fax:</strong> ' + fax + '<br><strong>E-mail:</strong> ' + email + '<br><strong>Website:</strong> ' + website + '<br><strong>FSA Number:</strong> ' + fsanumber + '<br><strong>Network:</strong> ' + network + '</p>');
```

$('#ajaxindicator').hide();

}

function validatePassword(){
  var clientpassword=$("#clientpassword").val();
  var currentpassword=$("#currentpassword").val();
  var currentpasswordmd5=hex_md5(currentpassword);
  if (currentpasswordmd5!=clientpassword){
   $("#messagebox").html("You input the wrong current password, please try again.");
   $('#ajaxindicator').hide();
  return false;
  } 
 }

I have a disabled textbox and some hidden ones. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try  to hide /show  progress bar on states of ajax request, please check through this code :

```
 jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(){
   jQuery("#loading-mask").show();
  });

 jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   jQuery("#loading-mask").hide();
 });
```

remove that $('#ajaxindicator').show(); from your code

Comment: Thanks Chirag! I've taken out the $('#ajaxindicator').show(); from the code and now the indicator appears for a split second then disappears. Thing is, the form still won't submit.